# Impossible System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

This is from a competition: DMM Olympiad, Ural State University P4

I don't understand what the question means exactly (the first part, i.e. "exclude $x$ or $y$ from..." part). Does it mean "write $x$ in terms of $y$ or $y$ in terms of $x$", or something else?

Exclude $x$ or $y$ from \begin{array}{l}2x^3+3xy^2-4x^2 y^2+y+1 = 0\\ 3x+5x^3 y^2-2xy^5-xy+2 = 0\\ \end{array}

Comment: we can solve equation 1 for $y$ and this can we plug in equation 2 and we have an equation only in $x$

Comment: I would guess it would mean solve for one in terms of the other...